# Suggesting ideal locations for column breaks in the multicols environment

Tags: multicol, multicolumn, columnbreak

I've tried using minipages (and had overflow off the bottom of the page).  I'm thinking of something along the lines of `\pagebreak[0]` but for suggesting column breaks.  Almost a `\columnbreak[0]`, if you will.

I have some text and then a linebreak and then a tikzpicture and then a new pagagraph and then we repeat the text, linebreak, tikzpicture a number more time.  The text and tikzpicture get separated between columns and pagebreaks so I figure if I could tell TeX that I'd rather have the columnbreak between the previous tikzpicture and the next text, then I could solve the problem.